# Adding a space after the first 4 digits of a phone number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’m trying to add a space after the first 4 digits of a phone number

Majority of the numbers are 11 digits but there are a handful with more and there are no spaces at all between the digits currently

Comment: If some are >11 digits, then they would presumably be prefixed with the country code, so splitting after 4 wouldn't be correct. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/display-numbers-as-phone-numbers-7feabe49-15b3-411c-a030-781b4f2c87dd though idk how flexible that is for variable digit counts.

Answer (score 3):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,4) & " " & MID(A1,5,99)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a *substring* into a *string* using `REPLACE`. With data in `A1` you could use:

```
=REPLACE(A1,5,0," ")
```

[image]

The trick here is to replace ***0*** characters.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are perfect for inserting a space character in between the 4th and 5th number however this may cause issues if you want the cells to still be treated as a number.

An alternative would be some custom formatting which will display a gap but won't actually insert one so the underlying data will stay as a number.

I preface this by saying that my knowledge of custom formatting is limited so if anyone can improve on this please do.

What I did was clicked on the expansion button under the Number formatting ribbon:
[image]

Then in the Custom tab in the Type box I added
`####" "#######`
[image]

Now as I said my knowledge of custom formatting is limited so this may not work with numbers of a different length but hopefully someone can expand on it.

Comment: This is the best answer so far - the one with the frame challenge. I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't actually want "the first 4" every time, but a formatting scheme for "phone numbers". The link in my comment under the OP has a link to an MS page on phone number formats, but I'm not au fait enough with Excel to test it through real variable-length phone numbers to be able to provide a proper answer.